# Regex: Basic pattern for date format (dd.mm.yyyy) not working

Tags: regex, regex-lookarounds

I am new to Regex and am trying to create a basic date pattern for a text input field in HTML.

**For now I only want to consider the following rules:**

- first number group with 2 digits from 01 to 31
- second number group with 2 digits from 01 to 12
- third number group with 4 digits from 1961 to 2100
- separator after first and second number group must be a dot / period

**Allowed examples:**

- 01.12.1990
- 04.05.2000
- 31.12.2010

I tried the following but this does not work for me.
Can someone tell me what I am missing here ?

**My Regex pattern:**

```
pattern="[01-31].[01-12].[1961-2100]"
```

**Update:**

`pattern` in my case is the HTML pattern attribute not a variable in JS.

Many thanks in advance,
Tom

Comment: That's not how [Character Classes](https://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html) work.

Comment: @AhmedAbdelhameed: Yes, that helps regarding the number groups. Thank a lot. How do I check that only dots / periods are allowed for the separator ?

Answer (score 1):

try this :

```
pattern = "(0[1-9]|1[0-9]|2[0-9]|3[0-1])\.(0[1-9]|1[0-2])\.(\d){4}";
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. This helps but it's missing the range for the last number group and it's not working for me. Note: pattern in my case is the HTML pattern attribute not a variable in JS.

Comment: im sorry! so try this instead of (\d) : (19[6-9][0-9]|20[0-9]{2}|2100)

Answer (score 1):

Try with this regex: `(0[1-9]|[12]\d|3[0-1])[\./]([0[1-9]|1[0-2])[\./](196[1-9]|19[7-9]\d|20\d\d|2100)`

#### [Demo](https://regex101.com/r/DqnIiq/30) here

Comment: Thanks a lot ! Looks like it's missing the years from 1980 to 1999 and it's not working for me.

Comment: @keewee279 check demo it will match 1980 to 1999

Comment: Thanks again. Unfortunately, it doesn't work for me this way. It only works if I skip the leading zeros on the first number group.

Comment: I found a way that works for me and posted it below.

Comment: @keewee279 i gave prefix 0 optional. now edited

Answer (score 0):

**I found a solution that works for me:**

```
pattern="(0[1-9]|[12][0-9]|[3][0-1])[\.]0*([1-9]|1[0-2])[\.](196[1-9]|19[7-9][0-9]|20[0-8][0-9]|209[0-9])"
```

Thanks,
Tom

Comment: Why so complex?: 20[0-8][0-9]|209[0-9]
rather than 2\d{3}